# How does Hibernate detect if a connection has been closed outside of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, c3p0

Im using Hibernate 4.3.11 with H2 1.4.199

To protect against occasional sessions getting seemingly stuck I set

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces", "true");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout","1500");
```

and this causes c3p0 to release the connection after that time period

```
   java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
            at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:555)
            at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
            at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
            at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
            at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:90)
            at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
            at com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(HibernateUtil.java:209)
            at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.java:469)
            at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:84)
            at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:37)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The trouble is when my code uses that now invalid connection HIbernate doesnt seem to know it has been cancelled

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-199]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:170)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1568)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosedForWrite(JdbcConnection.java:1557)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:561)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:860)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211)
        at com.jthink.songkong.util.SessionUtil.rollback(SessionUtil.java:25)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.RecordingOnlyMatcher.matchRecordingsOnlyByAcoustid(RecordingOnlyMatcher.java:452)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.matchSongs(AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.java:138)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.doTask(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:418)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.java:470)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:84)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:37)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Even though in my code I do check my session is open, txn active ectera

```
public static void rollback(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        if (session!=null && session.isOpen() && session.getTransaction() != null && !session.getTransaction().wasRolledBack())
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
    catch(HibernateException he)
    {
        //Hide erorr cause can occur after timeout txn
        MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, he.getMessage(), he);
    }
}
```

these don't seem to prevent the rollback() being called and then failing, I have similar problems with session.close()

Comment: try to add this propriety inside the youpr configurations `hibernate.c3p0.min_size`, `hibernate.c3p0.min_size`, `hibernate.c3p0.timeout`, `hibernate.c3p0.min_statements`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo How is this relevent ?